# php - file_get_contents/fread continuous input stream

Tags: php, http

For my project I have to communicate from my (php) website to remote devices. One of the commands that I need to implement sends a continuous stream of data until it receives more input from the user.

So my question is will this be a problem if I use `file_get_contents()`? Or should I use `fread()`? My input is in the form of a string which `fread()` says I should use `file_get_contents()`, however if I use `file_get_contents()` will I need to put it in a loop then between packets send data to my device to stop it sending data? Will a loop close my connection and open a new one each time I call `file_get_contents()`?

I am also limited on the amount of data I can use per day to the point where if I use `file_get_contents()` and it limits on chunk the chunk size of 8KB that is 8% of my data for the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fsockopen`, `fread`, etc... The purpose of `file_get_contents` is file reading, not to send/receive data the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `fopen` and use `stream_context_create`

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
    ),
);
$context = stream_create_context($options);
$fh = fopen($your_url, 'r', false, $context);
```

This will allow you to consume the stream as a file. Giving you access to any of the stuff you'd want to do with it... like parse it line by line with `fgets` or whatever.

Comment: I have to use `stream_create_context()` for what I am doing with file_get_contents right now anyway. Just to clarify does the stream for fopen sit in the background (probably on its own thread?) collecting the data in some buffer until I pull the data out of it?

Comment: As far as the threading, I'm not sure. You could look into the source and see. https://github.com/php/php-src. Data is collected in a buffer, waiting for you to read it. I never checked to see if letting things accumulate in the buffer affected the memory used by my script, mostly because I had to have some strong guarantees that I would process data faster than it arrived in the stream.